# What happens if a C# source file has more than 4 billion tokens?

Tags: c#, language-lawyer, roslyn

The [Roslyn overview](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Overview&referringTitle=Syntax%20Visualizer#SPANS) says:

> Spans
>
> Each node, token, or trivia knows its position within the source text
>   and the number of characters it consists of. A text position is
>   represented as a 32-bit integer, which is a zero-based Unicode
>   character index. A TextSpan object is the beginning position and a
>   count of characters, both represented as integers. If TextSpan has a
>   zero length, it refers to a location between two characters.

So what would happen if you tried to compile a valid C# source file with more than 4 billion tokens? Does the C# standard say anything about a maximum file size or maximum token number for a single C# source file?

Comment: You might be waiting a while for it to compile :-) That would be an 8GB source file (16GB if in UTF-16) minimum if you actually want 4 billion tokens. Half that for 2 billion tokens across 4 billion text positions.

Comment: I would say, if you want to compile a .cs file with more than 4B tokens, you should probably seek mental help ;)

Comment: Easy to underestimate how large 4 billion truly is.  A superhuman programmer that could write a *million* lines of code every month still needs 334 years to get in trouble.  Exceeding the CLR limits on metadata would be the first restriction encountered anyway.  Which has been done btw, auto-generating code is easier with Roslyn.

Comment: If we are to assume this question is relevant and useful in any possible way, then the best way to answer it is _for you to actually try it and see what happens_.

Comment: I've written a few code generating applications over the years. None have generated anything quite that large, but I have exceeded the number of tables allowed in a SQL Server query. Are you planning something more fiendish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So what would happen if you tried to compile a valid C# source file with more than 4 billion tokens?

It would fail. Your limit is in fact less than that since even if the integers are unsigned most tokens in practice would be larger than one character, and many tokens require whitespace separation between them. As such a character index would not suffice for even a fraction of that unless the C# code was something like `a+a+a+a+a+a…`

> Does the C# standard say anything about a maximum file size or maximum token number for a single C# source file?

No. Compilation unit (source files) is covered in section 9.1 which doesn't mention size limits.

This is as such a way in which Roslyn fails to meet all possible cases covered by the specification.

Software is though designed with particular use cases in mind. Many of them include "feasible to happen in the real world" as an implicit case.

If you've written something larger than that you are insane. And at least 7 years older when you finished than when you started (assuming constantly typing at the highest competiton-level typing speeds constantly without sleep, food or bathroom breaks). If you've generated this much code programmatically, you've almost certainly not taken the best approach; what size is the compiled program going to be?

If you **really** need to compile such a program, customising your compiler is probably going to come up for some other reason anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I've ever *tried* this, but the simple answer is probably "it would throw an overflow exception."

I don't imagine the C# spec says anything about it, because this is a limitation (albeit quite practical) of the implementation, and not the language. C# would have no issue with you having billions and trillions of tokens, that would fall under the scope of the compiler. I don't know if it's documented anywhere else, just since it's so unimportant, but it's quite possible that the compiler does have a maximum file size. Otherwise--and I say this as someone with quite limited knowledge of how it actually parses the document--it could easily run out of memory when running.

But as people have said in comments, you'd have much bigger issues if this became a problem for you. They write compilers very well, so if your code is too big for it to parse, that's probably your fault. I definitely understand that this is just a theoretical question on your part, and I respect that, but I doubt it's practical enough that there are many awesome answers out there.

On the other hand, if you were building your source code dynamically, that could become a problem. But again, if you're putting that many characters in a single document, that's not really the compiler's issue, and it's likely indicative of a bigger problem.